# Empty and Isset functions in php

Tags: php

I am working on a project. For my project, it requires user to enter inflation rate and rate of return of investment. If the user didn't enter anything, it will have default values of 3 and 4 respectively. Then if the user entered whatever value, it will be the value. (if the user entered 0, it will still post the 0. I have tried the following code but the default values do not work. Thank you for your time.

```
<html>
<p>
<b>Expected rate of return for investment (%):&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</b>
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $_POST['rinvestment'];?>"  min = "0" placeholder= "4" name="rinvestment" />
</p>

<p>
<b>Inflation Rate (%): </b>
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $_POST['inflation'];?>" min = "0" step = "0.1" name="inflation" placeholder= "3"/>
</p>

 <?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (isset($_POST['rinvestment'])){
$rinvestment=$_POST['rinvestment'];
}
else {
$rinvestment = 4;
}


if (isset($_POST['inflation'])){
$inflation=$_POST['inflation'];
}
else {
$inflation = 3;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Well you might want to read up on with [ISSET()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) actually does...

Comment: I am confused as to what you are trying to do. Can you make it more clear? Why are you checking for `isset` of a `POST` variable without sending any `POST` request?

Comment: @AcharyaAnurag sorry i didn't copy all my code, there are submit button too, so if the user click the submit button, it will post the value.

Comment: How do you want it to be if user enters 0 ?

Comment: @SerhatAkay then the value will be 0. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of the `isset()` variable is just as the name suggests - to check if a particular variable **is set**, i.e. if it exists.

In your case, despite the user not setting any values, the `$rinvestment` and `$inflation` variable **are being sent**, albeit as a null variable. Now since the `isset()` function always find the variable, it always returns `true`. This is why your code is not working.

You need to check for an empty variable to satisfy your condition, i.e.

```
if(!empty($inflation))
{
    //set default value
}
```

Although this gets your job done, it is recommended to check for `isset` of the `POST` variables to avoid errors.

Comment: I did try that but when user enters 0, the webpage will assume user didn't enter anything, so it will calculate use the default numbers which is not i want. Thank you for your time

Comment: In that case, you could make use of a simple radio button to ask user whether or not they want to add a custom value. This way your task becomes pretty simple!

Comment: Can I achieve that by just add few lines of coding?

Comment: Yes. If you could provide me with your full code, I could tweak it easily. It would save me the trouble of having to write the whole code myself.

Comment: However, I do not want to have any more buttons. For the type I want is it impossible? Like when the user enters 0, then it will post 0 but there is default values when !empty.

Comment: @RAABBIT Unfortunately, there is no way to do what you want using just the `empty()` function. [See the official documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Depending upon your exact need, there are **several** easy ways to get it done. To do that, you need to explain a bit more about your project or perhaps provide the relevant portion of the code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I read the document and i realize i can do that by adding !is_numeric($value). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` only checks if the value is set, the value can still be empty so try something like

```
if(isset($_POST["rinvestment"]) && !empty($_POST["rinvestment"])) {
    $rinvestment=$_POST['rinvestment'];
}
else {
    $rinvestment = 4;
}
```

if you want the if the user has `0` in the input field that it uses the default value, use this:

```
if(isset($_POST["rinvestment"]) && (int) $_POST["rinvestment"] > 0) {
    $rinvestment=$_POST['rinvestment'];
}
else {
    $rinvestment = 4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works, however, when user enter 0, the webpage will still think that is empty then return the default value. I hope when the user enter 0, it will post 0.